# The reasoning behind omitting "the" in "I'm (the) president of the United States."

Tags: articles

I understand you can say either

> I'm president of the United States.

or

> I'm **the** president of the United States.

I also know of a rule that you may omit "the" in front of a title, position, etc.

Since the omission does not seem to depend on the style of the text, I'd like to know what is the reasoning behind such a usage and rule.

Is it because you tend to consider a title something like a proper noun?

Comment: If "President" is used as a proper noun, the "P" should be capitalized, though.

Answer (score 2):

> When a predicative noun phrase names a unique role or job, either a
>   zero article or *the* is used.

‘Longman Student Grammar of Spoken and Written English'

Comment: I asked about the reasoning behind the rule, not the rule itself. And no one here seems to know any such reasoning or bother to think about it.

Answer (score 1):

My intuition is that:

1) "I'm president of the United States!" would be chosen to put more focus or emphasis on the power invested in the role - and less on the person. Read: How could anyone question the power of the person (me in this case) holding this office. I am shocked!

while

2) "I'm the president of the United States" might be chosen to emphasize the singularity of the office holder. Read: There is no one other than me who can make this decision, since I have that power exclusively.

While either intuition may be wrong, the point is that you would have to look at how the sentence is used in the **context** of the conversation its a part of. Grammar choices are constrained by the context - not so much by simple 'style'. 
At the risk if being repetitive; the decision is a result of the speaker's intent in that context.

Now, whether the constraints of grammar might restrict what or how can think or speak. Well...that's a debate for another day.