# Why "be king", not "be a king"?

Tags: nouns, articles, determiners, predicative-complements

I've heard people say "be king" (as in "I can't wait to be king") in movies and TV. Why don't they say "be a king"? Which is correct?

Comment: _King_ is a very potent word, and since there can only be one at a time, it's unique and can take all three varieties of article when it's a predicate noun. (_Droit de roi,_ after all). _Princess Charlotte can't be king; Princess Charlotte can't be a king; Princess Charlotte can't be the king._ All correct. Ditto for _Queen._

Comment: @John: But whereas Prince Charles could grammatically say (and I believe quite likely actually *has* said) *"I want to be [the] King"* with or without the article, it would have seemed a bit odd to me if Diana Spencer had said *"I want to be Princess"*. I can't make up my mind if I'd like that one any better with ***the*** (though ***a*** is fine), but either version seems fine with *"I want to be [the] Princess of Wales"*. I think this must be because of what you say - at any given time there can be multiple princesses, but only one Princess of Wales.

Comment: _Princess_ is not a unique term; there can be more than one at a time. That changes the specificity.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I think saying "Yakko became the king of Anvilania" emphasizes a change in Fred's status from being something else to being Anvilania's monarch, while "Yakko became king of Anvilania" would emphasize that identity of Anvilania's ruler changed from being someone else to being Yakko.  Which phraseology to use would depend upon which change was more important.

Comment: You can say both but in terms of meaning it essentially comes down to "Why do you want to _be **a** king_ when you could _be (**the**) king_?"

Comment: @supercat: At least one other person obviously agrees with you, but I have to say I think that's a completely spurious distinction. Sure, either of those two possible "emphases" might be implied. But I reckon if you asked every single native Anglophone alive whether including the definite article was more appropriate for one or the other intended meanings, the vast majority would say it makes no difference. And the rest (there wouldn't be many) would be about equally split between *your* assertion, and the precise opposite.

Comment: @FumbleFingers have I missed the memo or something? None of the answers posted have used the capitalized *king*. If someone is [King of England](http://www.historic-uk.com/HistoryUK/KingsQueensofBritain/), that is his title and it must be capitalized, surely? Changing the name of the country shouldn't make any difference.

Comment: @Mari-Lou: I think the memo has implicitly been doing the rounds [for the past century](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=will+be+king%2Cwill+be+King&year_start=1910&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwill%20be%20king%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwill%20be%20King%3B%2Cc0). As that NGram shows, 100 years ago the usage under consideration was as likely as not to be capitalised, but nowadays it's usually *not* (I mean specifically when the "adjectival" reference is to the *office*, rather than a "pronominal" reference to the *man* as a grammatical "subject").

Comment: @Mari-LouA They have now!

Comment: @FumbleFingers  Yes, *any* old king needn't be capitalized but what about King of France, King of Spain etc.?

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Either someone agrees with me, or just likes *Animaniacs*.  I was debating whether to say "King" [capitalized], but since I've seen "to be king" non-capitalized I didn't know that it mattered.  With regard to emphasis, reading it today my sense of which meaning is which is the opposite of what I wrote, so I don't know if I made a mistake, or if the language is totally ambiguous with regard to that distinction.  I do think such perceived differences in emphasis can have an effect on a reader's feelings toward people or characters, though perhaps word usage doesn't drive it here.

Comment: @supercat: [This NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=want+to+be+king%2Cwant+to+be+King%2Cwant+to+be+a+king%2Cwant+to+be+a+King%2Cwant+to+be+the+king%2Cwant+to+be+the+King&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwant%20to%20be%20king%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwant%20to%20be%20King%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwant%20to%20be%20a%20king%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwant%20to%20be%20a%20King%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwant%20to%20be%20the%20king%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwant%20to%20be%20the%20King%3B%2Cc0) clarifies a couple of points regarding how *common* the alternatives are...

Comment: ... 1) - Overall, no article at all is by far the most common usage. 2) ***King*** isn't normally capitalised in this exact context, *particularly* when the *indefinite* article is involved (no surprise there, since ***a*** implies the existence of multiple kings). But I seriously doubt many native speakers would interpret things any differently dependent on capitalisation - it's effectively optional, and increasingly the trend is *not* to capitalise.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Since "a king" uses an indefinite article, it suggests that he may become any one of a number of kings. In most cases where a person may become king, there is only one king in the political structure he inhabits. For instance, if he is in the line of succession for the English throne, he probably cannot become king of France or Denmark without marrying into that royal family. The equivalent phrase to "I can't wait to be king" would use a definite article - it could be rephrased as "I can't wait to be the king", since there is only one kingship he is eligible to accede to.

Comment: Precisely! The British heir on horseback at the white cliffs of Dover, if you will indulge me, is taking in the ocean and gazing at the rest of Europe across the English Channel, thinking to himself: "I want to be King so badly I can taste the blood of anyone standing in my way!". It is evident that the Price has plenty of stress and anticipation to deal with, and at worst he has been worn down by the formalities and traditions years before being crowned. Add the word 'a' just before 'King' however, and he now seems ready to betray his entire life to be crowned King elsewhere! In an instant!

Comment: @ProductionValues "I want to be a king... I'd prefer the kingship they've got waiting for me at home, but I'm open to better offers."

Comment: As a matter of fact, the next person to become king of Denmark will _almost certainly_ also be in the line of succession for the British throne (in the sense of being a legitimate descendant of Electress Sophia of Hanover with no Roman Catholics in the line of descent, as defined by the Act of Settlement 1701). As was already the case for the two _last_ persons to become King of Denmark, by the way.

Comment: @HenningMakholm The tangled history of royal intermarrying is so complicated! -_- I should've picked some fictional nations.

Comment: It's a lot simpler than this isn't it? Someone saying "I want to be a king" will be satisfied with being king of anywhere, someone who wants to be "the king" or "king" has a specific location in mind.

Comment: Why not "be the king" then?

Comment: @frnhr As stated in the last sentence of my answer, _it could be rephrased as "I can't wait to be the king"_

Comment: What's interesting is that, as King, you wouldn't describe yourself as simply "king." That is, when asked "who are you?" you couldn't respond "I am king." You would either say "I am a king," Or I am the king of France" or something. To the question "who are you *currently*," however,  you could respond without the article: "I am King of France."

Answer (score 11):

Context is the key.

1. An heir apparent, next in line, may say: "I can't wait to be king".
2. A candidate running for President can say: "Wait till I become President!"
3. Anybody wishing he were a king, would say: "I'd like to be a king".
4. Same goes for other contexts, such as in this one: "Think like a king!"

Comment: Yes, this is very important! In your examples 1 and 2, the speaker is talking about a kingship or presidency that already exists, whereas in 3 or 4 they're probably speaking metaphorically, and not talking about the king of anything in particular. Same with the phrase "live like a king".

Comment: And don't forget the Kipling story, filmed with Sean Connery and Michael Caine, "The Man Who Would Be King". We wouldn't use the indefinite, because it was king of somewhere specific; nor yet the definite, because until we read the story or see the film, we don't actually know king of where. So I reckon it takes the biscuit for generic kinghood.

Comment: @DavidPugh another reason not to use the definite article is that it ruins the iambic scansion.

Comment: @phoog. Upvote! I knew there was something tugging at my mind....

Comment: In your examples 1 & 2, the speaker could just as accurately said "a king/president".  To frame the question in context, don't refer to the speaker but the context in which he/she is speaking.  Steve Ballmer speaks to a room full of Microsoft executives, he is the president.  Steve Ballmer attends an industry meeting with executives from other companies, he is a president.

Comment: Yes, thanks @John! But I wanted to confine myself to the use of "a" versus without it, as it pertains to the question.

Comment: Sound good @Sankarane.

Answer (score 8):

*King* can either be a bare role NP, or part of a larger NP (NP is shorthand for *noun phrase*). A bare role NP is a singular noun that can occur without a determiner, in other words without a word like "*a*" or "*the*". These types of word almost always describe some kind of role, function, office or title. Other examples might be *Managing Director*, *Prime Minister*, or *Head of Sales*.

Of course, nearly always these nouns can also occur as the head of normal noun phrases, where, if they are singular, they must be accompanied by a determiner such as "*the*", *"a*" or "*my*", for example.

The choice between "*the*" and "*a*" or other determiners in such cases, is exactly the same as it is for any other noun. In relation to the word "*king*", it will probably depend on whether one is considering this king as one of a number of kings, in which case the preferred determiner would be "*a*" - or whether this king is being viewed as the only king, in which case we would favour "*the*".

Now, you may be given the impression from this that nouns occurring as bare role NPs are interchangeable with normal noun phrases. This is not so. A minor point is that a bare role NP nearly always picks out a unique specific title or role. In this respect, bare role NPs are similar to Proper Names. Furthermore, the organisation or body that this role is in relation to must be obvious from the discourse. If there are several managers in a particular organisation, you cannot *want to become Manager*. The reason in this case is that it is not clear which unique managerial role you wish to inhabit. If there are several kings under discussion, we cannot modify a bare role NP to show which one we want to refer to. So the following is malformed:

- *No, he is king I told you about yesterday. (ungrammatical)

The word *king* must immediately pick out the specific role being discussed.

Perhaps more importantly than all of this is that a bare role NP cannot, in normal circumstances, occur as a subject or object of a clause. The grammatical function of bare role NPs is almost entirely restricted to that of Predicative Complement. We normally only see bare role NPs, therefore, as complements of verbs such as *BE* or *BECOME*. The following sentences are therefore ungrammatical:

- *They killed King. (ungrammatical - *king* as direct object)
- *King ordered the execution of the chancellor. (ungrammatical - *king* as subject)
- *I was afraid of King. (ungrammatical - *king* as object complement of preposition).

Notice however, that bare role NPs can function as the complements of prepositions, where the complement is predicative, i.e. it describes an attribute of another entity in the sentence. Bare role NPs often occur as a complement of the preposition *as*:

- She performed very well as Managing Director.

**Conclusion**

All three forms of noun phrase, "*king*", "*a king*" and *the king*" are fully grammatical (and indeed there are many other determiners such as *this* or *some* which we could use with this noun).

If this word is a predicative complement, is being used such that it specifically refers to a role, not so much to an entity, and if this role is unique and easily identifiable by the listener, then we could use a bare role NP:

- He wanted to become King.

If we are considering an individual more than a role; if the king is being considered as one of many; if the phrase is not being used with a predicative function but as a direct object, subject or so forth; then we will have to use the word *king* as part of a normal noun phrase, where - if it is singular - it will have to occur with a suitable determiner. The range of determiners will be the same as for any other singular countable noun, and like other noun phrases, the determiner that is used will depend on the context.

Comment: “Oh my god, they killed [Kenny’s dog] King!”

Comment: Perhaps you could copy'n'paste this answer (well with minimum adjustments) and answer this three-year-old question. [The reasoning behind omitting “the” in “I'm (the) president of the United States.”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/93309/the-reasoning-behind-omitting-the-in-im-the-president-of-the-united-states)

Comment: @Mari-LouA Thanks, I'll do that. Might have to wait till tomorrow though ... Am off to the pub :)

Answer (score 3):

The "a" implies multiple kings whereas "to be king" implies the ultimate king of all.  So the latter packs more of a punch.

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking.  "Charles may be a king on Earth, but Jesus is the king of us all."... and similar such movie dialogue.

Answer (score 2):

Either one might be correct; it really depends on the context.

For example, in America people might say "I can't wait to be president" and we know we're talking about the American president, not any other president.

Answer (score 0):

Here, "king" (president, queen, et al..) is sometimes used as an **uncountable noun**. For instance, there is only *one* king, and there can only ever be *one* king for this kingdom.

---

EDIT: As @JohnLawler points out, "king" can take on all three article forms. It depends on the context and the meaning that is to be conveyed.

Answer (score 0):

Oddly enough, I think "to be king", "to be a king" and "to be the king" are all different.

If you say "to be a king", like recognizer says, it would imply one of any number of kings, whereas if you say "to be the king", it would imply one specific king of one specific kingdom.

On the other hand, if you say "to be king", it's like you're saying "to have the attributes and/or capabilities that come with being (a/the) king", whichever those are.

In other words, one can be "a king" or "the king" and still not "be king", if such states do not apportion to their monarchs the features of "being king". And, one can "be king" even without being "a king" or "the king", if such features are made available in some other way, unlikely as that may be.

Note that I'm not talking about metaphorical meanings of "king", here (like, say, the "king of rock'n'roll"), but of literal meanings, such as monarch or ruler.